# Split string when change case

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I want to split a string when change the case.

For example I have two strings: `ABCcd` and `abCDE`.

I would results `ABC` and `cd` on the first and `ab` and `CDE` on the second. Number of lower and upper case aren't defined.

I have already tried with `preg_match` and `preg_split` but I have some problem to define the right regular expressions.

Comment: So what is the problem? Please share the code you tried and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: I have tried differents regex expression like `/([a-z]+[A-Z]+)|([A-Z]+[a-z]+)/` or `/([a-z])?([A-Z])/` but are both wrong.

Comment: You could get a much better answer than "try-this" if you posted that before.

Comment: If you have tried these regex then you have seen that are verily wrong. So I have decided to not post these regex expressions. I'm sorry if I have wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simplest one.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794798)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$input = array("ABCcd","abCDE");
foreach ($input as $value)
{
    preg_match_all("#[A-Z]+|[a-z]+#", $value, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I've chosen your solution because I think it's the cleanest! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps matching zero width is an option.

**Regex:** `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
   $str = "aaaaBddDDDeeFFggJ"; 
   $match = preg_split("/(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/", $str); 

   foreach ($match as $value) {
        echo "$value \n";
    }
?>
```

**Input Strings:**

```
ABCcd
abCDE
aaaaBddDDDeeFFggJ
```

**Output:**

```
ABC
cd
ab
CDE
aaaa
B
dd
DDD
ee
FF
gg
J
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XK1977/2/)**

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Qq4qFx)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `preg_match_all` from php, that will give you an array with the results.

```
preg_match_all('([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)',"ABCdeFGhAAAss", $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

example: https://ideone.com/qITPI4